# Google Calendar API Timezone daylight and standard time issue

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

When I create an event giving it a near date, all works well.

But when I create an event which is a few months later, say that it falls in outside the daylight saving time period DST (while I am currently in the daylight saving time period), the event is created with an unwanted 1 hour offset.

The code below results in the following output:

`Starts 2020-12-20 9:00 Ends 2020-12-20 11:00`

```
 $event = array(
        'summary' => $attributes['summary'],
        'location' => $attributes['location'],
        'description' => $attributes['description'],
        'start' => array(
            'dateTime' => 2020-12-20T10:10:00-04:00',
            'timeZone' => 'America/Toronto',
        ),
        'end' => array(
            'dateTime' => 2020-12-20T10:12:00-04:00',
            'timeZone' => 'America/Toronto',
        ),
        'anyoneCanAddSelf'=>true,
        'guestsCanInviteOthers'=>true,
    );
```

**Question**

How should I change my code so it works automatically and so that I don't need to manually change my code / the offset twice a year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are overspecifying the `dateTime` parameter to include an *offset*, but you are also providing a `timeZone` parameter. In this case, the `timeZone` parameter is conflicting with the offset value in the `dateTime` (America/Toronto is offset -05:00 on that date).

Given the conflict between the two - it chooses to use the offset specified in the `dateTime`.

The [documentation for the Event resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) specifies, in the `end.dateTime` attribute:

> The time, as a combined date-time value (formatted according to RFC3339). A time zone offset is required **unless a time zone is explicitly specified in timeZone.**

(emphasis added)

The easiest way to solve the problem would be to remove the offset value from the `dateTime` you specify and rely on the `timeZone` setting.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. It works using this code format: 'start' => array(
            'dateTime' => 2020-12-20T10:10:00-04:00:00',
            'timeZone' => 'America/Toronto',
        ),